# Extracting a computer name from a string

Tags: c#

I'm looking for the best way to extract the computer name from a predictably formatted string. The string will always be in this format:

```
C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\NOOBCOMPUTER\\...
```

If there is a way to extract the contents of a string between the third pair of backslashes and the fourth pair, that should work.

Though I have no idea where to begin with the regex to achieve that, nor do I know if regex is the most "foolproof" way of going about this in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string and then inspect each element.

```
string [] s = yourstring.Split("\\");
string final = s[3];
```

Comment: This wouldn't compile. Should be single quotes, not double.

Comment: Confirmed this works, once you correct the double quotes to single quotes.